# Get last 6 months timestamps revealing duplicates on certain days

Tags: php

I have the below simple code to retrieve timestamps for the previous 6 months. Which has been working fine, however today on the 31st Dec; July is appearing twice, and December is appearing twice.

This brings me to an irrational fear of dealing with time in PHP

```
for ($i = 6; $i >= 0; $i--) {
    $time_start = strtotime('first day of this month 00:00:00', strtotime('-' . $i . ' months'));
    $time_end = strtotime('last day of this month 23:59:59', strtotime('-' . $i . ' months'));
    $timestamps[] = [
        'label' => date('M', $time_start),
        'start' => $time_start,
        'end' => $time_end
    ];
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [label] => Jul
            [start] => 1561903200
            [end] => 1564581540
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [label] => Jul
            [start] => 1561903200
            [end] => 1564581540
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [label] => Aug
            [start] => 1564581600
            [end] => 1567259940
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [label] => Oct
            [start] => 1569852000
            [end] => 1572530340
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [label] => Oct
            [start] => 1569852000
            [end] => 1572530340
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [label] => Dec
            [start] => 1575122400
            [end] => 1577800740
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [label] => Dec
            [start] => 1575122400
            [end] => 1577800740
        )

)
```

I have an assumption that `strtotime('-1 month')` doesn't actually subtract a full month?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was right in assuming that `strtotime('-1 month')` fails to subtract a full chronological month.

My solution was to subtract using `DateTime` instead which is feeling more accurate

```
for ($i = 5; $i >= 0; $i--) {
    $start = new DateTime('first day of this month 00:00:00');
    $start->modify('-' . $i . ' months');
    $time_start = strtotime('first day of this month 00:00', $start->getTimestamp());
    $time_end = strtotime('last day of this month 23:59', $start->getTimestamp());
    $timestamps[] = [
        'label' => date('M', $time_start),
        'start' => $time_start,
        'end' => $time_end
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the results you are getting is that today is December 31. When you use `strtotime('-' . $i . ' months')` you get the following sequence of dates:

```
31 December
31 November
31 October
31 September
31 August
31 July
31 June
```

PHP conveniently recognises that three of these dates are illegal and converts them into its best guess, leaving you with:

```
31 December
 1 December
31 October
 1 October
31 August
31 July
 1 July
```

Hence the duplications (and the missing September and November) you see in your output. As you saw, using `DateTime` is the best way to work around this.